# How to make server port free (or reset) using java code/patch

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java project. I am using a JADE server for listening
the port and receiving the data. Also, I am using MATLAB terminal to run
a script that sends output to java console. I need to run this MATLAB
script multiple times.

But for each iteration, I have to reset the server port. Without doing
so, it is throwing a binding socket error.

I wish to know, is there a way (java code/patch) that can free and reset
the used port (socket port) after each run of the program? In eclipse, I
can make free a port by clicking on "red" button on console. However, my
project should be independent of such clicking.

Comment: Yes, you should stop the previous one. Otherwise, the old program does not know that it should free the socket. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460745/restart-an-application-in-eclipse or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385313/restarting-an-app-in-eclipse especially that restart plugin looks promising. Or use the STS version of eclipse http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v340/NewAndNoteworthy.html which has such a button built-in.

Answer (score 3):

socket.[setReuseAddress(true);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setReuseAddress(boolean))

> Enable/disable the SO_REUSEADDR socket option.
>   When a TCP connection is closed the connection may remain in a timeout state for a period of time after the connection is closed (typically known as the TIME_WAIT state or 2MSL wait state). For applications using a well known socket address or port it may not be possible to bind a socket to the required SocketAddress if there is a connection in the timeout state involving the socket address or port.
>
> Enabling SO_REUSEADDR prior to binding the socket using bind(SocketAddress) allows the socket to be bound even though a previous connection is in a timeout state.
>
> When a Socket is created the initial setting of SO_REUSEADDR is disabled.
>
> The behaviour when SO_REUSEADDR is enabled or disabled after a socket is bound (See isBound()) is not defined.